# How do I recover a saved password from the lobby config file?

Tags: zero-k

I am signed into the Zero-K lobby on one computer, which I don't have access to right now. I want to sign in on another computer, but it turns out I can't remember the password. (Everyone should use OpenID like Stack Exchange does!)

When I get the first computer back, will I be able to read my password from the `ZeroKLobbyConfig.xml` file there, or is it stored with encryption I'd have to decompile the lobby executable to reverse?

I'd rather not follow the lost-password procedure if I can avoid it. It involves PMing an admin on the forum, so it seems I'll only be able to do this from the computer that's already logged in anyway. D'oh.